# Create claim-based Rest WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, wif, adfs

I have two domains. Each one has ADFS. In domain B I have a claim based SOAP WCF service and in domain A I have an active client. The client knows through configuration only, to:

1. Go to A's ADFS and get a token.
2. Go to B's ADFS with A's token and get a token for the SOAP WCF service.
3. Access the WS with the token.

It all works fine. Now I want to replace the SOAP WCF with Rest WCF.

I want to make the client to go to the ADFS through the config like it works now, not through the code. Is this possible? How would I configure the client and the service?